# Postgresql - Unable to create stored procedure as defintion contains temporary table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

In postgresql 13, I am inserting data of a table into temporary table at run time. Query works fine when executed. But when I try to create store procedure on top of the query it fails with error: **ERROR:  "temp" is not a known variable**

Can someone please help me to understand what am I missing?

[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/dUFuDqU-)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dbo.<proc-name>()
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $$
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS child;
SELECT Id, Name
into TEMP TABLE child
FROM dbo.master;


COMMIT;
END;
$$;
```

Thanks

Comment: (1) That's not what SELECT INTO does in pl/pgsql, is it? Check the docs. (2) You will need to use dynamic sql to work with TEMP tables because of course compiled references to a temporary table don't go together well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RichardHuxton but my question is Why the query does not work inside the stored procedure whereas when executed directly it executes without issues. So, why do I have to go with dynamic SQL for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ... INTO` is PL/pgSQL syntax to store a query result in a variable. You should use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`.